# google glass quickstart for python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am having trouble getting the Quickstart working properly. I am new to Python and GAE and I am not a full-time programmmer, but have developed before. However, I have Python 2.7 and GAE properly installed (win7), but the Quickstart does not tell me where in my app directory to put the generated "session.secret" file. I put it in the app root "mirror-quickstart-python" folder. When I try to run the app on the dev webserver via the GAE Launcher, it throws errors (log shown below).

I have successfully deployed another sample app (guestbook), here: http://smlqadtest.appspot.com/ So I think I am close. To get this far in Python, I had to learn about Jinja2, pip, distribute_setup.py, and a bunch of other stuff. It looks like it needs PIL, too, but on Win64 there seems to be issues witch lead me down a rathole. But I am not sure I need that. Anyway, I'd love some help on getting this going! Thanks! Scott

```
=========GAE Launcher Log Console Output===========

2013-07-07 22:47:50 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py'​, '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=9080', '--admin_port=8001', 'C:\\Users\\sml\\Documents\\GitHub\\mirror-quickst​art-python']"
INFO 2013-07-07 22:47:53,789 devappserver2.py:528] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING 2013-07-07 22:47:53,808 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO 2013-07-07 22:47:53,821 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:61560
INFO 2013-07-07 22:47:53,825 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:9080
INFO 2013-07-07 22:47:53,831 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8001
INFO 2013-07-08 05:48:09,594 discovery.py:190] URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/mirro​r/v1/rest?userIp=127.0.0.1

INFO 2013-07-07 22:48:11,641 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
ERROR 2013-07-08 05:48:11,651 webapp2.py:1528] Property "client_id" is not configured.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 1511, in __call__

rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 1505, in __call__

rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher

return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 1077, in __call__

return handler.dispatch()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 547, in dispatch

return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\weba​pp2.py", line 545, in dispatch

return method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sml\Documents\GitHub\mirror-quickstart-p​ython\oauth\handler.py", line 55, in get

flow = self.create_oauth_flow()

File "C:\Users\sml\Documents\GitHub\mirror-quickstart-p​ython\oauth\handler.py", line 42, in create_oauth_flow

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope=SCOPES)

File "lib\oauth2client\util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper

return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "lib\oauth2client\client.py", line 1343, in flow_from_clientsecrets

client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename, cache=cache)

File "lib\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 145, in loadfile

return _loadfile(filename)

File "lib\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 108, in _loadfile

return _validate_clientsecrets(obj)

File "lib\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 85, in _validate_clientsecrets

'Property "%s" is not configured.' % prop_name)

InvalidClientSecretsError: Property "client_id" is not configured.

INFO 2013-07-07 22:48:11,673 server.py:593] default: "GET /auth HTTP/1.1" 500 228
INFO 2013-07-07 22:48:11,786 server.py:593] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 154

=============================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that you haven't set the client ID for your project:

```
ERROR ... Property "client_id" is not configured.
```

Edit `client_secrets.json` and populate it with values that you take from the API console per [this step](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/python#configuring_the_project) in the setup process.

For example, if your APIs console looks like this:
[image]
then your `client_secrets.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "1234.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "ITS_A_SECRET_TO_EVERYBODY",
    "redirect_uris": [
    ],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jenny! I *thought* I did that, but the 'session.secret' file may also have been in the wrong directory. I started over and got it going, feel free to read my blog post on 'beginner tips' here => https://plus.google.com/u/0/110113915393251652573/posts/PSDJUyJNwJE